# illegal instruction (core dumped) on ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I am trying to run C project written in Linux on my ubuntu virtual machine installed on Windows 10. The makefile is compiled successfully with no errors. Then when I try to run the main file: I got "illegal instruction (core dumped)".
The console prints some lines of the code, and then it stopped. (Specifically, it stops at fflush(stdout)).

How I can solve this error? I should do something with memory assigned to virtual machine? Or it is related to the code itself? Note, that the code is running well on Linux machine.

Comment: Have you used `gdb` or `valgrind`?  Are you building with all warnings enabled and resolving them as they come up?

Comment: Also, please include an [mcve] in your question. There's not much anybody can do to help right now.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean with gdb or vagrind. The makefile uses g++ compiler. Are the warnings results after "make all" the main reason?

Comment: Did you run your program using `gdb` (or any debugger really) or `valgrind`? You can find guides using your favorite search engine. Both are likely to assist with this issue. If you're getting warnings, start fixing them and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: Yes, the makefile run it using g++.